# Relative nonrestrictive clause: "where they can debut unreleased and sought-after music"

Tags: grammar

> It has been designed to become an artist’s haven for unannounced top DJ performances where they can debut unreleased and sought-after music.

What kind of clause is "where they can debut unreleased and sought-after music"? Noun, adverb, or relative?

I'm guessing it's not a noun clause, but I could be wrong. I'm leaning towards relative adjective clause.

Answer (score 2):

Structurally, it can't be a Noun Clause because the last words before it: "unannounced top DJ performances" already make up a Noun Phrase.

It can be either an Adverb Clause or, like what you strongly feel, an Adjective Clause.

But semantically, "where they can debut unreleased and sought-after music" doesn't really perform the function of an Adverb in that sentence.

This is why it's an Adjective Clause.

Answer (score 2):

> *where they can debut unreleased and sought-after music*

is a restrictive [Relative Clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/relatives.pdf) that modifies the entire Noun Phrase

> *an artist’s **haven** for unannounced top DJ performances*

This NP has *haven* as its head noun. Since *haven* can have a locative sense, it can be modified by a locative relative clause beginning with *where* (similarly, only NPs that can have temporal senses can be modified by relative clauses with *when*).

And, since it modifies the entire NP, it has to go after it, which means after the prepositional phrase at the end. That's all, really.